# JavaFX Issue in MOUSE_CLICKED event propagation

Tags: javafx

I am encountering an inconsistent behavior with `MOUSE_CLICKED` event propagation. Below is the scenario in which I am having the issues:

**Background:**

I have an editable `TableView`, where some action needs to be performed on click of a `TableCell`. So I included the below eventHandler in the TableCell constructor.

```
addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
    System.out.println("!!! THIS NEEDS TO BE TRIGGERED ON EVERY CLICK !!!");
});
```

And the underlying implementation for editable TableCell factory is to show text in the `Label` (set as graphic of cell) and when editing, the `Label` is replaced with `TextField`. I have other requirements which I cannot achieve if I use `setText()` method of the TableCell. So for that reason I am using `Label` as graphic.

So far everything works well., that when I click on the cell it is turing into edit mode and the `MOUSE_CLICKED` handler is firing.

**Issue:**

Instead of clicking on the empty space in the cell, if I directly click on the `Label`, the edit behaviour works well but the `MOUSE_CLICKED` handler is not fired. Upon some debugging, I noticed that the cell edit is triggred on MOUSE_RELEASED event and as in the startEdit() the MOUSE_RELEASED target(Label) is removed and replaced with TextField, the `MOUSE_CLICKED` event is not propagated to cell. This analysis has convinced me why the `MOUSE_CLICKED` handler is not triggered when I directly click on `Label` (as the `Label` doesn't exist in the scenegraph anymore).

But what confuses me is that this behavior is not consistent. Lets say if I click on the `Label` of Cell-A for the first time, the edit and `MOUSE_CLICKED` handler are working fine. And from there on, only the edit is triggered and not the `MOUSE_CLICKED` handler.

Now if I click on the `Label` of Cell-B for the first time,. it is the same behavior, works for the first click but not for the other consecutive clicks.  The confusing part is, if again click on Cell-A label, works for the first time but not the consecutive ones.

Below is the quick demo that demonstrates the issue:

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EditableTableViewDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final ObservableList<TableDataObj> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        final int no = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
            final String firstName = "First Name " + i;
            final String lastName = "Last Name " + i;
            final String city = "City " + i;
            items.add(new TableDataObj(firstName, lastName, city));
        }

        final ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
        cc.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        cc.setFillWidth(true);

        final TableView<TableDataObj> tacticalTable = buildTable();
        tacticalTable.setItems(items);

        final GridPane pane1 = new GridPane();
        pane1.setVgap(5);
        pane1.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        pane1.addRow(0, new Label());
        pane1.addRow(1, tacticalTable);
        pane1.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
        HBox.setHgrow(pane1, Priority.ALWAYS);

        final VBox vb = new VBox();
        vb.setSpacing(10);
        vb.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        vb.getChildren().addAll(pane1);
        VBox.setVgrow(pane1, Priority.ALWAYS);

        final Scene sc = new Scene(vb);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Editable Table Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private TableView<TableDataObj> buildTable() {
        final TableView<TableDataObj> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        final TableColumn<TableDataObj, String> fnCol = new TableColumn<>();
        fnCol.setText("First Name");
        fnCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().firstNameProperty());
        fnCol.setPrefWidth(150);

        final TableColumn<TableDataObj, String> lnCol = new TableColumn<>();
        lnCol.setText("Last Name");
        lnCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().lastNameProperty());
        lnCol.setPrefWidth(150);

        final TableColumn<TableDataObj, String> cityCol = new TableColumn<>();
        cityCol.setEditable(true);
        cityCol.setText("City");
        cityCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().cityProperty());
        cityCol.setPrefWidth(150);
        cityCol.setCellFactory(param -> {
            final EditingCell<TableDataObj, String> cell = new EditingCell<>();
            cell.setOnMouseClicked(e -> cell.startEdit());
            return cell;
        });
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(fnCol, lnCol, cityCol);
        return tableView;
    }

    class EditingCell<T, S> extends TableCell<T, S> {

        public EditingCell() {
            addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
                System.out.println("MOUSE_PRESSED on cell '" + getItem() + "' with target :: " + e.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName());
            });

            /* Doesn't make any difference if I changed the below addEventHandler to addEventFilter */
            addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
                System.out.println("!!! THIS NEEDS TO BE TRIGGERED ON EVERY CLICK !!!");
            });
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        }

        private TextField textField;

        private Label label = new Label();

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            label.setText(getString());
            setGraphic(label);
        }

        @Override
        public void commitEdit(final S newValue) {
            super.commitEdit(newValue);
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();
            if (textField == null) {
                createTextField();
            }
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.selectAll();
            textField.requestFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(final S item, final boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText(getString());
                    }
                    setGraphic(textField);
                } else {
                    label.setText(getString());
                    setGraphic(label);
                }
            }
        }

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.setMinWidth(getWidth() - getGraphicTextGap() * 2);

            textField.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {
                if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                    keyEvent.consume();
                } else if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit(getItem());
                    keyEvent.consume();
                }
            });

            /* Cancel edit when loosing focus. */
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, prevFocus, focused) -> {
                if (!focused) {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            });
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }
    }

    class TableDataObj {

        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();

        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();

        private final StringProperty city = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public TableDataObj(final String fn, final String ln, final String cty) {
            setFirstName(fn);
            setLastName(ln);
            setCity(cty);
        }

        public StringProperty cityProperty() {
            return city;
        }

        public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setCity(final String city1) {
            city.set(city1);
        }

        public void setFirstName(final String firstName1) {
            firstName.set(firstName1);
        }

        public void setLastName(final String lastName1) {
            lastName.set(lastName1);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is as below:

```
MOUSE_PRESSED on cell 'City 0' with target :: LabeledText
!!! THIS NEEDS TO BE TRIGGERED ON EVERY CLICK !!!
MOUSE_PRESSED on cell 'City 0' with target :: LabeledText
MOUSE_PRESSED on cell 'City 0' with target :: LabeledText
MOUSE_PRESSED on cell 'City 0' with target :: LabeledText

MOUSE_PRESSED on cell 'City 1' with target :: LabeledText
!!! THIS NEEDS TO BE TRIGGERED ON EVERY CLICK !!!
MOUSE_PRESSED on cell 'City 1' with target :: LabeledText
MOUSE_PRESSED on cell 'City 1' with target :: LabeledText
MOUSE_PRESSED on cell 'City 1' with target :: LabeledText

MOUSE_PRESSED on cell 'City 0' with target :: LabeledText
!!! THIS NEEDS TO BE TRIGGERED ON EVERY CLICK !!!
MOUSE_PRESSED on cell 'City 0' with target :: LabeledText
MOUSE_PRESSED on cell 'City 0' with target :: LabeledText
MOUSE_PRESSED on cell 'City 0' with target :: LabeledText
```

In the above output, On first click on Label of cell, the edit and MOUSE_CLICKED handler are fired and from the second click onwards only the edit is triggered but not the MOUSE_CLICKED handler.

So my question here is: Is this behaviour an issue in JavaFX or am I missing some crucial info that causes this inconsistency? This behaviour is observed on both JavaFX8 and JavaFX18.

Comment: I'm not sure why that's happening. But does `label.setMouseTransparent(true);` fix the problem for you?

Comment: not near my IDE, just a couple of untested and potentially unrelated comments: do not modify the scenegraph in updateItem but only in edit life-cycle methods (and then do it completely, in both cancel and commit), why the textField for an empty cell?, use action to trigger a commit ..

Comment: have a look with scenicView on which components are really showing at any time, check who gets the released - clicked will only happen if both pressed and released are received by the same node

Comment: @Slaw, my first thought to fix this issue is to set the `label.setMouseTransparent(true);`. As for other requirements, I need to show tooltip on Label. So I cannot completely disable mouse events on Label.

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for pointing the code changes. I just overlooked them. Corrected the code. I do investigated about the CLICKED events propagation,... I think the logic in ClickGenerator class of Scene.java is generating different results.

Comment: somehow overlooked the analysis part, sry, was too early in the day ;) I faintly remember that the cell behavior has its fingers into the mouse handling - if the cell is already selected, it starts the edit on released (that is both your clicked handlers are not notified because there is no clicked generated for the cell. The other way round: if not yet selected, the behaviour selects, and the clicked is delivered to both handlers of the cell.

Comment: if mouseTransparent == false is not an option, you could try to move the functionality of from the clicked into a released, that seems to be working always (at least if you cleanup the cell implementation as suggested in my first comment, didn't try if it's working with yours)